# How does Android Studio know about new dependency versions?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio seems to know when there's a newer version of a dependency. 
Maven repositories have all the versions so of course it can check there but it doesn't do it for all dependencies.

Noticed that it works for com.google and com.android dependencies but not for others. Why is that? Can it be configured?
Any insight on this is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio this check is path of Lint checks. You can see it here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/GradleDetector.java

And deps are hardcoded in this file:

```
    } else if ("com.google.guava".equals(dependency.getGroupId()) &&
            "guava".equals(dependency.getArtifactId())) {
        version = getNewerRevision(dependency, new PreciseRevision(18, 0));
```

Comment: You can manually trigger the check for all the dependencies by doing Analyze -> Run Inspection By Name -> Newer Library Versions Available.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle does it for you. Notice that the suggested versions depend on the gradle version. If you are using an outdated gradle version you won't get these suggestions.

Comment: Could you elaborate? How does Gradle then do it then? And how does AS get this info from Gradle?

Comment: Gradle checks the maven central repository for newer versions of dependencies you have added. If they are not the latest it informs you.

Comment: @Nishad Then why doesn't it work for other libraries, such as `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'`, which is now at `2.5.2`?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to check all deps, you can use this plugin https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

Add to your build.gradle call:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
```

And then execute task:

```
./gradlew dependencyUpdates
```

Comment: Sure, but AS already does it without plugins. More interested in getting it working in plain AS